# Sorting binary numbers according to this order relation and finding k-th largest.

Tags: algorithms, order-theory, binary

We have the following  order relation on positive integers: 
let number A be less than number B in two cases:

• When the binary notation of A has fewer "ones" than B has.

• When the binary notation of A contains the same amount of "ones" that B has, then A is less than B when A is less than B in decimal notation

How would i quickly determine the k-th largest number in this order ?

I need tips im stuck .

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**. Observe that, since the binary representation of $2^n$ is $1$ followed by $n$ zeros, one has $2^0 < 2^1 < 2^2 < 2^3 < \cdots\ $ for your order. Then compare these numbers with numbers having at least two ones in their binary representation.

Comment: I maybe didnt ask the question properly. I want to find kth largest from 0 to  some N inclusive where these numbers are sorted according to the relation. I see that we have 0, 1,2,4,8 ... for 1 one in binary then 3 , 5, 6,9 ,10 with 2 ones and i see that those can be formed by addition like 2+1 , 4+1,2+4 etc but i dont really understand the pattern behind it :C